# udoo and sicklms

Tags: ros, laser, sicklms, ros-hydro, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i am running ubuntu 13.04 on UDOO and ros hydro. I have been trying to install sicktoolbox_wrapper on udoo since yesterday by following the "using sicklms" guide but unfortunately i get stuck at the first step, when i try to do "rosdep update" i get an error which says "AssertionError: unable to handle 'index' format version '2' please update rosdistro.

But when i try to update it tells me "python-rosdistro is already the newest version".Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183220/udoo-and-sicklms/) by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-07-04**:
Plz split your tags by spaces not #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was resolved by switching to the current ARM repository at http://packages.namniart.com/ros . See: http://answers.ros.org/question/190925/udoo-sicktoolbox/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0